# isfolder & HasChildren not working with modx 2.3

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I can't make [[!HasChildren]] & [[*isfolder]] work with modx 2.3, it always display the same result with the checkbox container checked... Is it normal ? Is there an alternative ?

```
[[*isfolder:is=`1`:then=`toto`:else=`titi`]]
```

Comment: http://bobsguides.com/blog.html/2013/04/27/understanding-isfolder-and-haschildren()/

Answer (score 1):

Snippet `get_childrens_count`

```
<?php
$count = 0;
$criteria = array(
    'parent' => $modx->resource->get('id'),
    'deleted' => false,
    'published' => true,
);
$count = $modx->getCount('modResource', $criteria);
return $count;
```

usage:

```
[[!get_childrens_count:gt=`0`:then=`toto`:else=`titi`]]
```